# .click After .render

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little script that was supplied to me and wondered how I might achieve the following having tried all manner of ways.

I need to fire a .click event on a DIV (called cbaButton1) AFTER the .render has fired from the below script.

I have tried onload in various ways to no avail.  I can make the div fade etc but I cannot make the link click and fire the associated functions.

```
  new CBA.Widgets.StandardCheckoutWidget({
merchantId:'XXXXXX',
orderInput: { 
    format: "XML",
    value: "<?php echo $cart->createOrderInputValue(); ?>"

},
    buttonSettings: { size: 'large',color:'orange',background:'white'}  })     .render("cbaButton1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving that much information, but I will try. This is assuming you can change your script and renderfunction.

It sounds like you want to use some sort of callbackfunction. Edit your renderfunction to receive a second parameter which is an anonymous function and call it after your renderfunction is done. Example:

Calling the function:

```
.render("chaButton1", function() {
$('#cbaButton1').click();
});
```

The renderfunction:

```
function render(button, callback) {
   // Do something with the button. 

   // If the callback parameter is sent, call it as a function. 
   if(callback)
      callback();
   }
}
```

I don't know if this is any help, but you supply very little information.